# How to process the Execute Flume source and sink processor in NiFi?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I had set the configuration for the flume processors with the help of documentation link given below

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/.

But still there is an issue related to missing flume jar files, Is there is any need to add those dependency jar files or else some other problem, If it is because of those missing jar files then how should we add those jar files.

Comment: What flume sources and sinks were you trying to use? and what jar files are missing?

Comment: When I process the data through the execute flume source processor it throws an class not found exception, after adding that related dependency jar file in lib folder, it solves that exception and shows another class missing[exception] like wise it going on ... Is there is a need to add or build a flume dependency jar files